# Using Reset and Normalizer in Scss

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-lint

I had a question about including `reset/normalizer` files in scss. When I create a new file, say `_normal.scss`, and copy/paste the normalizer css into the file, once I save it creates a duplicate css file.  So within that folder, I'll have:

1. `normal.scss`
2. `normal.css`

When I go to my imports file, to `@import "../Resets/_normal.scss"`, should I also be importing the .css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need it once. Sass can import a CSS just like a SCSS file, so I would advise leaving normalizer as a .css file and placing it in a "vendor" (e.g. `@import "../../vendor/normal.css`) or "3rdparty" folder in your project but outside of the scope of your Sass converter/watcher. Or better still, include it in your project via NPM. This way you are decoupling your code from the code of 3rd party libraries.